Spring boot Issue with more than one @RestControllerAdvice having two handler methods for same exception
I have two @RestControllerAdvice classes (ExceptionHandler1 , ExceptionHandler2). Both of them have a handler method which is mapped for SQL exception.
I have the access to modify the second controller advice class(ExceptionHandler2).
When an SQL exception is thrown , I want to route it to the handler method in ExceptionHandler2 rest controller advice class, but the handler method in ExceptionHandler1 is what is getting called.
Here are the two handlers.
//ExceptionHandler1
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler1 {
   
   @ExceptionHandler(SQL exception.class)
   @ResposeStatus(code = Http status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
   public void handleSQLException() {
   }


//ExceptionHandler2

@RestControllerAdvice

public class ExceptionHandler2 {

   

   @ExceptionHandler(SQL exception.class)

   public <T extends SQLException> ResponseEntity<Error> handleSQLException() {

       return new ResponseEntity<>(new Error(), Http status.CONFLICT);

   }


When an SQL exception is thrown , I want to route it to the handler method in ExceptionHandler2 rest controller advice class, but the handler method in ExceptionHandler1 is what is getting called.

ExceptionHandler1  is there in a dependent jar , and I can't modify that class. ExceptionHandler2 is in my package and I can modify it.
